# Can knex-postgis be used with bookshelf

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

Has anyone used knex-postgis
https://github.com/jfgodoy/knex-postgis
with bookshelf? The docs show how it bolts onto knex, which is great. I use knex through bookshelf and cannot get my head around how to get it working.

```
'use strict';

var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host     : 'XXXXXXX.com',
    user     : 'XXXX',
    password : 'XXXXXX',
    database : 'XXXXX',
    searchPath: 'public'
  }
});

// var st = require('knex-postgis')(knex);
var bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry');
bookshelf.plugin('virtuals')

module.exports = bookshelf;
```

This is how I have knex and bookshelf set up but I am not sure how this...

```
var st = require('knex-postgis')(knex);
```

ties in when making bookshelf queries later on.

Comment: You would need to access knex from the query method using the queryback

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

Create a Bookshelf model (insert into the DB) with a geo column (in this case, my Bookshelf model is a model called `Event` with a `geo` column that represents a PostGIS point):

```
new Event({
  geo: st.geomFromText(`Point(${lat} ${lng})`, 4326)
})
.save()
// ...
```

Now when you query it again, you can use the transform capabilities of the `knex-postgis` library to transform your points:

```
Event.collection().query((qb) => {
  qb.select('*', st.asGeoJSON('geo'));
}).fetch().then((collection) => {
  // collection.geo will contain a GeoJSON representation of your column.
});
```